# Unable to Perform Name Resolution

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network

My MacBook Pro, for some reason, detects the wireless connection, but I cannot go to a web page using Safari. I can open the iTunes Store, but cannot access my email. I ran the Network Assistant and it reflects that my connection is good. I tried putting in a manual IP address but my computer is still unable to perform name resolution to go to any web page. My home WiFi uses a WEP password, and configure IPv4 using DHCP.

I went to a local McDonald's to see if I could access the Internet with their free WiFi - my MacBook connected immediately and went out to several websites with no issues.

*Note*:
I went through all of the steps as listed [in this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/55134/9058) on June 30, 2012 with this very same situation but am still not able to open a Web Page.

Comment: Title should say Unable to Perform Name Resolution

Comment: You should be able to edit the question yourself, see the 'edit' link at the bottom of the question

Comment: Did you run the Network Assistant from Preferences->Network?

Comment: Can you use the ping and ping like google.com site(s)

Comment: We would need the make, model and the settings for your home-wifi set up, beyond just saying it is a WEP, do you have things like firewall enabled in you home network.

Comment: Patrix & Buscar-Thank you SO MUCH for your quick responses!!! Patrix-Tk you for your info re:editing my question. Yes I have run the Network Assistant from Preferences>Network. It requests the WEP Password, which is entered correctly, then continues to search, without ever connecting to my home WiFi. Buscar:I tried using the ping, setting it up per the instructions for Google 8.8.8.8., but there is still no connection. I have all of the info you requested in your last post Buscar - where do I send this?  Not sure if it is secure posting it here?  Again-thank you both for your expertise!!!!

Comment: Buscar - there isn't a firewall enabled in my home network.  Sometimes we have to block the internet connection for my kiddo's xbox going by the IP address.  Yesterday when this action was taken - my MacBook was blocked - the IP addresses had changed on the administrator's computer (???).  This has happened before, & we have had to rename all users/devices.  We unblocked my Macbook's internet access, but still had this problem.  This is the first time it hasn't been resolved when this situation has arisen.  Turning the router on/off has worked in the past also - but to no avail now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the MacBook connection problems only happen when you have blocked the kiddo's x-box, correct?

Does removing the X-Box block allow you to connect to web and email?

If so, the problem is likely happening because of DHCP.  DHCP means the router hands out IP addresses.  Usually, DHCP will hand out IP addresses in the order that devices connect to the router.

For Example:
1st - 192.168.0.1 -> MacBook
2nd - 192.168.0.2 -> X-Box  [BLOCKED]

Now lets say the kid reboots the router while you are away.  Now the X-Box connects to wifi first and gets the first IP address. When you get home you get the second [blocked] address 
For Example:
1st - 192.168.0.1 -> X-Box 
2nd - 192.168.0.2 [BLOCKED]-> MacBook

Setting up your MacBook with a manual address (DHCP with manual address ) might work... but only if you chose an unused IP address in the "proper IP address range" for your router.

If the above is similar to your situation ... The solution to this depends on the make and model of your router.

My router has an option for "DHCP with reserved addresses".  This will reserve and assign a specific IP address to a specific device.
Example: 
192.168.0.8 -[BLOCKED] [RESERVED for X-Box] .

The "reservations" are based on a device's "MAC Address". The "MAC address" is a unique "serial number" for the for a devices WiFi or ether (MAC address is nothing to due with MAC OS.)

Another option is to set the IPs manually but this would could be a pain... There may be other options depending on the make and model of your router.

Please let us know more about your router and router setup.